# Multiple wsgi.mod on single apache

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I have one `django3` application on apache `http://myapp.example.com`

For now it works, but I want to put second `django3` application on the same server with `Anaconda`.

Is it possible? if so , How should I set `WSGIPythonPath` and `Alias /static/` for each application??

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ServerName myapp.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/myapp/current/"
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myapp_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myapp_access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html/myapp/current/>
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/myapp/current/myapp/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess py37 user=ubuntu group=ubuntu python-path=/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages
</VirtualHost>

LoadModule wsgi_module /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py37.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

WSGIPythonHome /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/py37/
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/myapp/current/

<Directory /var/www/html/myapp/current>
  <Files wsgi.py>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static/ /var/www/html/myapp/current/static/
Alias /media/ /var/www/html/myapp/current/media/
<Directory /var/www/html/myapp/current/static>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply clone the virtual host and replace the paths relevant for the new application, you may need to move the directory alias:

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/html/myapp/current/static/
Alias /media/ /var/www/html/myapp/current/media/
<Directory /var/www/html/myapp/current/static>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

into the virtual host. I do not use the wsgi.py but a site.wsgi. Which runs the app.
Its content is:

```
import os
import sys
import site

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('{{PATH TO}/site-packages')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('{PATH TO PROJECT}')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = '{PROJECT}.settings'

# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("{PATH TO}/bin/activate_venv.py")
exec(open(activate_env).read(), dict(__file__=activate_env))

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

What works on my stage is(httpd.conf):

```
LoadModule wsgi_module {PATH TO}/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
```

and the pyhton path/script is set in the virtual host instead in the main file:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess {GROUP} threads=1 python-home={PATH TO} python-path={PATH TO APP} user={USER}
WSGIProcessGroup {GROUP}


WSGIScriptAlias / {PATH TO FILE}/site.wsgi
```

you may need to comment the line that starts the application in your wsgi.py if you want to use the settings above